# Cannot connect to docker image port MacOS (kafka/kafdrop etc)

Tags: macos, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am building three images kafka/kafdrop/elastic, each exposed to different ports. For example, kafdrop

```
66012c0676bf        obsidiandynamics/kafdrop:3.23.0                       "/kafdrop.sh"            9 minutes ago       Up 3 seconds        0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp                       project_kafdrop_1
```

I was able to browse kafdrop webpage with http://localhost:9000 in my previous macbook pro (an earlier version of catalina).

I got a new macbook (catalina 10.15.4), after that I rebuilt the images with the same docker-compose.yml. I can see the containers built successfully and running on port 0.0.0.0:9000. However, when I tried to browse the webpage, it showed not able to connect.

docker-compose.yml

```
zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.4.9
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_PORT: 2181
    volumes:
      - /Users/xxx/opt/project/data/zookeeper/data:/data
      - /Users/xxx/opt/project/data/zookeeper/datalog:/datalog
    restart: unless-stopped

  kafdrop:
    # image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop:3.23.0
    ports:
     - '9000:9000'
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: kafka:19092
      JVM_OPTS: "-Xms32M -Xmx64M"
      SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXTPATH: "/kafdrop"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Any clue? If this is an issue with Mac or Docker?

Thanks.

Comment: Please share your docker-compose.yml

Comment: thanks for comments. I have added docker-compose.yml

Comment: I pruned all images and re-run docker-compose. Now it is working. Still do not know what happened ...

Comment: You question has no kafka container